# In BottomAppBar the navigation drawer item click doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I have implemented a BottomAppBar in my app.
Following this article [Implementing BottomAppBar menu and Navigation drawer Control](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-c4f069e579ec)

Everything works just fine but the problem is that the navigation drawer items doesn't show Toast or anything else. In a word it don't get any click.
Here's my source code [Github](https://github.com/nullsaint/BottomAppBar)

I also tried Log.d in onNavigationItemSelectedListener but it doesn't also show anything to Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationView` belongs to `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment` ,
You should do below in fragment `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment` class:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_item1:
                            ...
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_item2:
                            ...
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_item3:
                            ...
                            break;
                        default:
                            ...
                            break;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

And you also need get `navigationView`  in fragment.

**Edited**:

In fragment:

```
@Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout,
                container, false);
        NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView )view.findViewById(.....);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        ....
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: didn't catch the last thing you said that i also need get navigationView in fragment.

Comment: NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView )view.findViewById(.....)

Comment: @MDFARHAN view is populated in OnCreatedView() method in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try setting MenuItem ClickListener manually and see if it works for you.

```
BottomAppBar bar = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);

bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle actions based on the menu item
        return true;
    }
});
```